# Another way to concatenate

Tags: javascript

Is there another a way to concatenate a '#' character like I'm doing below?

radioButtonID = '#' + radioButtonID;

Comment: That should work (assuming radioButtonID is a string). You mean is there another way?

Comment: yea another way, more compact...

Comment: updated...to be more clear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    "#".concat(radioButtonID)
or
    ["#",radioButtonID].join('')
```

Comment: why do you have to use " as opposed to 2 ' ?

Comment: You don't single and double quotes are usually interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var radioButtonID = ['#', radioButtonID].join('');
```

Comment: Nice. It's like Javascript calisthenics.

Answer (score 2):

That's about as short as it could get if you are prefixing.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with what you've got there? That should work.

Unless you're looking for a stringbuffer or something...

Comment: Nothing just wondered if there was a shorter way basically in JS, cause I did not find one.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but this works:

```
radioButtonID.replace(/(.+)/,"#$1")
```